# Data Import FROM Postgres SQL_ASCII database TO SQL Sevrer 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql

I want to import data from a Postgres database to a SQL Server database.

The Postgres database is using SQL-ASCII encoding because the databse was migrate from old ISAM database.

So, if I want to Import the data into SQL Server I have two problems:

1. Characters like ä,ü,ö are not supported
2. Numeric Default type not supported too.

For Dataimport I use Postgres SQL Native Provider in Microsoft Integration Services.
To convert the data about dataconverting in Microsoft Integration Services not running.
To try convert data directly in postgres - Example:
convert_to(lieferanten.lief02::text, 'UTF8'::name) AS convert_to
--> Result in SQL Server is   --> can not Import!

So I don't know how I can solve this Problem. Anybody have idea or can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Fix the data in PostgreSQL first.

There may be several different character-sets and encodings mixed up in the database (since SQL-ASCII makes no guarantees about the data).

It can be as simple as dumping the database and running iconv against it, or it can be a tedious semi-manual process of correcting value-by-value.

Once you can import it into PostgreSQL as UTF-8 (or ISO-whatever) then you can transfer it to SQL Server.